# More efficient way of removing element with two digits from a columns

Tags: pandas

Given code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":['浙A','京E','12','34','b','c','d']})
df
```

with table

```
    item
0   浙A
1   京E
2   12
3   34
4   b
5   c
6   d
```

I want to make two digits entry as nan

expected output:

```
item    result
0   浙A  浙A
1   京E  京E
2   12  NaN
3   34  NaN
4   b   b
5   c   c
6   d   d
```

what's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need replace if there is 2 digits and also possible another values:

```
df['result'] = df['item'].replace('\d{2}', np.nan, regex=True)
```

Or if need repalce only 2 digits and no another substring values:

```
df['result'] = df['item'].replace('^\d{2}$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
  item result
0   浙A     浙A
1   京E     京E
2   12    NaN
3   34    NaN
4    b      b
5    c      c
6    d      d
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if `item` is `numeric` and its `length` is 2 using [`Series.str.numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) and [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
In [962]: df['result'] = np.where(df.item.str.isnumeric() & df.item.str.len().eq(2), np.nan, df.item)

In [963]: df
Out[963]: 
  item result
0   浙A     浙A
1   京E     京E
2   12    NaN
3   34    NaN
4    b      b
5    c      c
6    d      d
```

Answer (score 0):

using `np.where` with `pd.to_numeric` and `divmod` to test the digits.

As we are only testing integers, I believe this would be more efficient as opposed to working with strings.

```
import numpy as np
df['item_new'] = np.where(
    (pd.to_numeric(df['item'],errors='coerce') // 10).ge(1),
    np.nan,
    df['item'])

  item item_new
0   浙A       浙A
1   京E       京E
2   12      NaN
3   34      NaN
4    b        b
5    c        c
6    d        d
```